# Django: Added m2m via through causes 'current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions

I am trying to add an m2m relationship via a through table and, out of the blue, am encountering the following error:

'current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block'

There are 2 odd issues about this. The first is that, I've successfully migrated/synced all of my relevant apps. The second is that both the associated models and the model in question (AddedFeature) successfully save into the database even if the error is thrown. That is, even though the transaction is aborted, the AddedFeature instance is saved to the DB.

http://dpaste.com/1357120/

Just to reiterate - refreshing my DB and remigrating/resyncing did *not* help solve the issue.

Comment: Turn off your `debug_toolbar` and see if it changes the exception message.

Comment: That worked! I have no idea why though and how to fix it.

Comment: It is because part of your code that's under transaction management is raising an exception you are not handling (by rolling back the transaction to a savepoint) and later when middleware is processing response it comes to django_toolbar middleware which does sql queries during transaction that has been aborted by your code thus raising the exception you've experienced. That's a one, long sentence :O

Answer (score 1):

Look for the problem that happened *before* this error. Your code, or code you're using, is ignoring a database error. So the next operation fails.

You need to look in the database and/or application logs to find the previous problem. Then determine what part of your app's code is swallowing a database exception without logging it and aborting the transaction.

Setting `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` can be useful for this.